# Extract every number in the list and reconstruct the list?

Tags: list, scheme

I need to create this function `flat` that's supposed to re-contract a new list from the input list (but here, the input list can have a nested list inside):

ex. flat of (A (B (C) D) A) is (A B C D A)

My algorithm is the following, not sure if it's correct:

1. Check if the list is empty: if not, go on; if yes, done -- return the empty list
2. If the list has length 1, done -- return the list
3. If list has length more than 1, what do I do now? (I can use `car` and `cdr` to extract the list, but in either case, how can I make it recursively extract the list to the end, and I'm thinking use append to re-construct the list after.)

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If the list has length 1 it could still look like `((1))` and thus must be `flat`-tened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is that, if the list isn't `null?`, you shouldn't focus on the length of the list passed in to `flat`, but instead check to see whether the `car` of the list is a list itself or just an atom. If it's a list itself, you want to flatten it, as well as flattening the `cdr` of the list.

**EDIT:** Well, consider what happens in two different cases, one where you use `cons` and one where you use `append`:

```
(append '(a b c) '(d e f)) => (a b c d e f)

(cons '(a b c) '(d e f)) => '((a b c) d e f)
```

In the first case, you get a flat list back, and in the second case, you don't get a flat list back. You might then try

```
(define (bad-flatten lst) 
  (if ((null? lst) 
      '()
      (append (car (flatten lst)) (cdr (flatten lst)))))
```

but it won't work if the `car` of `lst` *isn't* a list. You need a third case, using `cond`, like so:

```
(define (incomplete-flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 
         '())
        ((list? (car lst)) 
         (append (flatten (car lst)) (flatten (cdr lst))))
        (else 
         ;; you need to do something different here. I can
         ;; think of at least two options.
        )))
```

Comment: yea how can I do that? to flatten the list? more help please. I know I need to flatten it. but how?

Comment: okay right, check if its a list. Do I use append ? or Cons ? 
If it is cons I can only add 2 at a time. So add the car with what ever is rest and recursively call the function again.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most optimized solution. Probably you can improve it further:

```
(define (list-flatten lst)
  (if (not (null? lst))
      (let loop ((args lst) (ret (list)) (c null))
         (if (not (null? args))
           (begin
             (set! c (car args))
             (cond ((list? c) (loop (cdr args) (append ret (list-flatten c)) c))
             (else (loop (cdr args) (append ret (list c)) c))))
           ret))
       #f))
```

Comment: I am reminded how amazingly ugly LISP is... I wish it felt good to talk down about LISP, but alas I like it too much.